# How would you solve this with as few ifs as possible?

Tags: java, arrays

Given 2 int arrays, a and b, return a new array length 2 containing, as much as will fit, the elements from a followed by the elements from b. The arrays may be any length, including 0, but there will be 2 or more elements available between the 2 arrays.

```
make2({4, 5}, {1, 2, 3}) → {4, 5}
make2({4}, {1, 2, 3}) → {4, 1}
make2({}, {1, 2}) → {1, 2}
```

A basic way would be this:

```
public int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
int[] c = new int[]{0,0};
if(a.length<1 && b.length>1)
  c = new int[]{b[0],b[1]};
if(a.length ==1 && b.length==1)
  c = new int[]{a[0],b[0]};
if(a.length ==1 && b.length>=2)
  c = new int[]{a[0],b[0]};
if(a.length >=2 && b.length<2)
  c = new int[]{a[0],a[1]};
if((a.length>=2)&&(b.length>=2))
  c= new int[]{a[0],a[1]};
return c;
}
```

The exercise is from [CodingBat.com](http://codingbat.com)

Comment: If this is an exercise, perhaps you should be doing this yourself.

Comment: Try to use a [decision table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table) to see which options/combinations have the same results and which conditions to use.

Comment: @ChristopherWirt, yes, I am doing it. That was an alternate way. I want to find several alternate solutions to it using only the basic things in java. I want to find an optimized way of doing it.

Comment: It can, of course, be done without any `if` statements at all.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not what the creator of this problem had in mind, but what the heck:

```
static Integer[] combine( Integer[] a, Integer[]b ){
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
    intList.addAll( Arrays.asList( a ) );
    intList.addAll( Arrays.asList( b ) );
    return Arrays.copyOf( intList.toArray( a ), 2 );
}
```

In a more conventional approach:

```
static Integer[] combine( Integer[] a, Integer[]b ){
    if( a.length >= 2 ){
        return Arrays.copyOf( a, 2 );
    } else {
        if( a.length == 1 ){
            return new Integer[]{ a[0], b[0] };
        } else {
            return Arrays.copyOf( b, 2 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution here is exactly what I'd have done.

Comment: @DanTemple really, what if the arrays had a million elements each?

Comment: @JamieCockburn "What if pigs had wings?" Clearly, this is a simple exercise for creating program logic with a single specific property at its minimum - one may ignore all other issues in such a case.

Comment: @JamieCockburn That's a fair question. Your solution would be better in that sense, but I doubt if the application here is required to be super optimized for larger data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Use some loops!

```
public static int[] make2(int[]... arrays) {
    int[] result = new int[2];
    int i = 0;
    for (int[] array : arrays) {
        for (int value : array) {
            result[i++] = value;
            if (i > 1)
                return result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you don't like the varargs parameter, you can do this instead:

```
public static int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[][] arrays = new int[][] {a, b};
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie! I will mark this as an alternate solution using varargs.

Comment: There's a version without varargs for you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I solved it. Total of 2 if statements.

```
public int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a.length == 0) {
        return new int[] {b[0], b[1]};
    }
    if (a.length > 1) {
        return new int[] {a[0], a[1]};
    }
    return new int[] {a[0], b[0]};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might be better off posting this type of question to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Don't do it in the way you did, no matter how many if there are, because the solution is extremely narrow to a specific case (think of having to use 3 numbers now) and it does not make any use of Java-typical features. Better try to think of a more general solution and make use of at least Java classes.

Independently from that remark, just iterate through your source lists/arrays until you have enough in your target.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am considering another solution by iterating through the arrays using for loops. I am trying to find alternate ways without using iterators and so on.

Comment: No problems with downvotes, but it would be nice to leave a remark what is wrong with the answer...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is dynamic and pretty short:

```java
public int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] result = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (i < a.length) {
            result[i] = a[i];
        } else
            result[i] = b[Math.abs(i - a.length)];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).